# Incorrect definition of html pattern

Tags: html, input

I am trying to create an html input validation that checks the input starts with a letter and ends with a number (and has 6 characters although this is not critical).
I have tried this:-

```
Salesperson: 
<input type="text" id= "name" pattern="[a-z]{0-9-_\.]{6}" placeholder="Salesperson ID">
```

This gives an error that the pattern is not matched. 
Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: I edited to display the code that was hidden but my edit is waiting for review...